# How do I mount a RAID in Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, raid

First, I'm a total newbie to this platform and only have a very basic knowledge of command line input in Terminal...

Long story short, I have a five disk LaCie RAID box (RAID 5) that seems to have had a hardware failure within the box itself, not just a drive. I am trying to rescue the information contained on the drives. 4 of the 5 still seem to be intact. Via bits and pieces of articles on the web I have gotten Ubuntu to recognize them as part of the same RAID, but I'm at a loss as to how to get the RAID to mount so I can access it on my network (Mac environment) and back up the data to a new drive.

I can't seem to find any command line inputs which make sense for my situation, and I'm not having any luck installing a GUI mounting app either. I tried several times to install pysdm, but could never get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about OSX are off-topic here.

Comment: BTW, what I have read is that Lacie has its own Linux OS that controls the Raid, you should be able to find out how to connect to that in your manual, and run diagnostics from that.

Comment: My question isn't based on OS X, its about Ubuntu. I thought it might help to know which environment I will be using to access and copy the drive once I have it mounted in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to mount the drive,

Run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Locate the drive and the mount it with

```
sudo mount /dev/sd## /location to mount
```

FYI replace ## with your corresponding drive. Also make sure you have created the directory where you intend to mount

If you are then trying to make the mounted drive network accessible through Ubuntu, use Samba. There is plenty of documentation on this on the Internet. [start here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One more question... how do I determine the "location to mount"? Also, if the original shares had login credentials will I need to provide that in order to mount them?

Comment: Please vote up 1 if this answer worked for you

Comment: Also configure samba server, not client. Then edit /etc/samba/smb.cnf to list your shares

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with the original share as you have it mounted locally. You can configure authentication in samba but if you are just using this to transfer data off the drive, I would configure anonymous access as it is easier. For the location. Cd /etc/media then mkdir (whatever you want to call the directory) then the location would be /etc/media/(your directory)

Comment: Thank you so much! This all pretty much makes sense, so I will give it a shot as soon as I get home tonight.

Comment: K please vote up when it works as stated earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You said it is RAID5 correct, RAID 5 is set up to rebuild itself if a drive fails, you need to look at your Lacie instructions, it should tell you that you replace the bad drive in the RAID set, and then the Lacie will rebuild the data on the drive.

RAID 5 is what is called a stripe set, each drive contains data from the other drives that will allow the RAID to rebuild itself.

Lacie I believe is a hardware raid, which means your drives are probably hot swappable, so you don't even have to shut down the Lacie device to do this.  Read your manual, that is my best answer.

Comment: This is all true, but aside from the one possible drive failure, there also seems to be a hardware failure inside the box itself. The entire NAS dropped off of my network and all attempts to make it visible and/or mount have failed. That's why I've removed the drives and attached them to a system running Ubuntu.